# sed double quotes vs single quotes

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace some text that has the symbol `$` in it:

- `echo "\$hello = false" | sed -re "s/(\$hello = )false/\1true/"` > **$hello = false**
- `echo "\$hello = false" | sed -re 's/(\$hello = )false/\1true/'` > **$hello = true**

Why does the single quote version work, but not the double quote?

Comment: `"\$"` = `$`, `'\$'` = `\$`

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because in double quotes backslash `\` is characters used to escaping so shell removes it when escaping. So it isn't passed on to sed.
Try:

```
echo "s/(\$hello = )false/\1true/"
echo 's/(\$hello = )false/\1true/'
```

Comment: Oh, I see. So if I wanted to use the double quote version I'd have to use 3 backslashes like so `echo "s/(\\\$hello = )false/\1true/"`. Thanks!